# Where in the object-oriented design process is an architecture pattern chosen?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, object-oriented-analysis

Most object oriented analysis and design books and resources describe the process where the analysis phase is followed by identifying classes. I understand that experience will often give you an idea of which architecture (if any) you should apply but is there a specific point in the object oriented design phase where this should occur? I'm about to start a large personal project and I want to make sure my choice of architecture doesn't disregard something from the analysis phase.

Comment: Analysis precedes design as far as I am concerned, and architecture comes first in design (although not all design patterns are architectural). But don't rely too much on these cookbook approaches. The whole process is iterative and interdependent, unless the project is enormous, when you would be using something like PRINCE anyway.

Comment: Specifically, I was wondering if the overall architecture should always be decided before trying to identify any classes. Based on the OOAD processes I've seen, candidate objects are are extracted from requirements and use cases which lead to actual classes. If that's the case, do I try to make a decision about architecture based on the classes that are initially modeled or should architecture be decided before any modeling of the domain.

Comment: This is known as he 'waterfall model': an ideal, feedback-free, unidirectional design & implementation process. It was discredited as long ago as the 1960s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question implies that architectural patterns are chosen all at once. In an ideal world (where requirements don't change, and where developers can read a client/stakeholder's mind), it might be possible to come up with a huge design up front, and stick to it. That never happens. The only way to come up with software that is both functional and well designed is to constantly refactor as requirements become more clear. And at each stage of refactoring, it's possible that a subsystem requires a different architectural pattern.

Of course, it's important to enter a project with some kind of "plan of attack". But don't expect the design phase to be over once that is completed. No one understands all the requirements up front (even if you're your own client). Things will always change.

In short, if you're not choosing architectural patterns throughout the development process, you're either a mind reader, or you're racking up technical debt.